# Separation of multiple overlapping normal distributions

Tags: distributions, biostatistics, mixture-distribution, probit, software

The problem is separation of multiple normal distributions of fish length, each normal distribution representing a distinct year class contributing to the overall population in a long-lived species.  Marian Y Y Yong in 1975 announced a Fortran IV program ENORMSEP in Fishery Bulletin vol. 73 to accomplish this task, combining probit analysis and regression analysis, but did not publish the program.  Is there current software out there that can tackle this problem?

Comment: It sounds to me that you want to fit a mixture of a given fixed number of normal distributions.  If so there is a lot of theory for doing this. One approach is maximum likelihood.  I expect that there is a lot of software available to do this.  However, the ENORMSEP program that you describe sounds like it is a very different approach to this problem.

Comment: The [VGAM R package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/VGAM/index.html) may be of help.

Comment: A quick fit of the distribution can be done in R.   http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10062/which-r-package-to-use-to-calculate-component-parameters-for-a-mixture-model/10070#10070

Comment: In SAS, I think PROC FMM could help with this.